# passing a php variable to js

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to pass a `PHP` variable to a `JS` document and display it as a part of a `String`. 
My code looks like:

php doc:

```
<?php

    $id = "57.pdf";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var id = <?php echo json_encode($id); ?>;
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../pdfjs/web/viewer.js"></script>
```

js doc:

```
var DEFAULT_URL = '../../html/docs/' + id;
```

However, the passed id variable doesn't show up as a part of the string in the `DEFAULT_URL` variable. Anyway, if I try to alert the passed variable, it shows up normally.

Comment: do you use document.ready in your js file?

Comment: why do you *json_encode* your id ?

Comment: @Oddant and anybody else who answered: Because this ensures that the value has proper Javascript syntax!

Comment: @Jakub Forget about PHP for a second, just hardcode your Javascript variable value. If it still doesn't work (likely), you have a simple Javascript problem of scope or execution order; nothing to do with PHP. We can't say more without seeing more of your script.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
var DEFAULT_URL = '../../html/docs/' + window.id;
```

Edit: then this should work (you should replace My by a name very specific to you).

```
<?php
    $id = "57.pdf";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var My = {
    app: {
        id: <?php echo json_encode($id); ?>
    }
 };
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../pdfjs/web/viewer.js"></script>
```

And:

```
var DEFAULT_URL = '../../html/docs/' + My.app.id;
```

Comment: The result I get is following: /html/docs/undefined

Comment: @JakubSedlacek: http://jsfiddle.net/ - please post your entire code so we can stop guessing in the dark.

Comment: @JakubSedlacek Sébastien's explanation (in other answer and comments) is right. What I suggest in my edit is namespacing you variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, I still get a refference error My is not defined.

Comment: My entire code is pretty long, so I won't post it now. However, it can be found at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js . It is the web folder. (viewer.js)

Answer (score 1):

The answer of this question is **NOT** `json_encode`. In fact, `json_encode` will ensure that the variable can be passed safely to JS, which is beneficial.

Consider [**this PHPfiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FmUJKe), which is exactly the OP's code. The `alert` goes through okay.

What I am betting on in this case is a structure similar to this:

```
var id = "57.pdf";
(function() {
  ...
  var id;
  alert(id);
})();
```

In which `id` has been re-declared local in the IETF, and the outside `id` is no longer accessible as a result. From there, the `alert` will be empty. It is impossible to know without seeing all of the OP's code, however.

Comment: Yes, the alert works fine either. The problem is with appending the variable id to the DEFAULT_VAR variable.

Comment: @Sébastien We're on the same assumption. If you're right my answer should work.

Comment: @rixo: Not necessarily. The other possibility is that he (or another script of his) is polluting the global namespace the same way he is, and redefining/unsetting `window.id` by omitting the `var` keyword. Difficult to telepathically guess, though.

Comment: @JakubSedlacek: your assignment has nothing to do with it. You've either re-scoped `id` somewhere down your code, or you've overwritten `window.id` by re-assigning `id` without `var` somewhere in your code. You could `alert(id)` instead of your `DEFAULT_VAR` assign - you'll get an empty box.

Comment: @rixo: Looks like it's namespace pollution :-)

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Looks less and less like that to me. Do you have an explanation on how he can get 'My is not defined' with my code?

Comment: Well, again, alert function works fine with My.app.id. However, var DEFAULT_URL = '../../html/docs/' + My.app.id; does return that id is not defined

Comment: Alright, problem solved in other way. Thanks for the responses. Jakub

Comment: @JakubSedlacek May we know how? I'm really puzzled by your situation...